# Good repository organization practice for Java properties files

Tags: java, svn, properties, repository

I maintain a multi-platform development framework that attempts to configure environment variables based on certain system and environment information that is inferred via various means. Once I infer these variables, I store them in a Java properties file for later use. This file could also be edited by the user of my framework (a developer).

I have a class called `Env` that manages this properties file, and it's in a package called `org.myproject.config`. I'm currently storing the default properties file in `src/org/myproject/config`. I'm wondering, is it good practice to store a config-type file under this directory of my project? Not sure where to go with this. Any input is appreciated.

-tjw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Java [Preferences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html) API if you wish to maintain platform neutrality.  Once you specify a file path, you make a lot of assumptions about the environment your application is running on.

Comment: Prefs API doesn't really fit my use-case. My preferences are not constantly in flux; they are set once for the lifetime of the environment. Only if the environment changes (not likely) are they changed.

Comment: I wouldn't disqualify the Preferences API based on that premise.

Comment: It uses platform-depended backing store. This backing store is one of the very variables which I determine on initial invocation, so I'd therefore have a chicken/egg problem as well unless I altered my current design. It's overkill, I'd be catching a fish with dynamite.

Comment: The point however, is that you do not have to maintain the backing store.  What exactly is your chicken/egg problem using the Preferences API?

Comment: hm, ok. I just read some more about java prefs and it seems like it might result in better design. thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

From what we experienced, environment specific information should not be stored on a repository. Someone updates by mistake an file and when he commits other users/environments are affected. We keep environment configuration separate and local on each environment. In our case the environment variables are stored in database tables, and the only environment information we have in property files is the minimum required fields to create a JDBC connection to the location of the environment variables. updates to environments pass through a IT change request or are done via an software upgrade.

Comment: The ones stored in svn are default preferences that are applicable for any platform. It may in fact be useful to revise this file from time to time. Where else can a file like this be stored?